# Data not added in database this is basically add to cart system

Tags: php, html, ajax

When I click add to cart button the **product id is fetched**, but when I click for store data into the database, so the data is not stored in database.

Ajax page is *main.js* and the PHP page is *action.php*.

```
<button pid='$pro_id' id='product' class='btn btn-danger'>Add to cart</button> 

$("body").delegate("#product","click",function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var p_id=$(this).attr('pid');
    $.ajex({
        url     : "action.php",
        method  : "POST",
        data    : {addToCart:1,proId:pid},
        success :function(data){
            alert(data);
        }
    })
})

if(isset($_POST["addToCart"])){
    $p_id=$_POST["proId"];
    $user_id=$_SESSION["uid"];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM cart WHERE p_id = '$p_id' AND user_id = '$user_id'";
    $run_query = mysqli_query($db->_link,$sql);
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($run_query);
        if($count > 0)
        {
            echo " product already added ";
        }
        else {
            $sql =  "SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_id='$p_id'";
            $run_query = mysqli_query($db->_link,$sql);
            $row = mysqli_fetch_array($run_query);
                $id=$row["product_id"];
                $pro_name=$row["product_title"];
                $pro_image=$row["product_image"];
                $pro_price=$row["product_price"];
                $sql= "INSERT INTO cart(p_id, user_id, product_title,
                 product_image, qty, price, total_amt) 
                VALUES ('$p_id','$user_id','$pro_name','$pro_image','1','$pro_price','$pro_price')";
                if(mysqli_query($db->_link,$sql)){
                    echo " product added.. ";
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors? can we assume all `VALUES` are valid?

Comment: Try using prepared statement instead of direct values that provide SQL Injection and errors.

Comment: yes, I never see any type of error.Lev Buchel

Comment: I think the problem is held to calling Ajax. Ajax does not call properly I don't know why.